# Tracking drag-and-drop operations with C++ and WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop, clipboard, win32gui

Currently, I'm working on some copying monitor software that tracks transferring of files from external storage devices to internal and vice versa.

At the moment, I've identified two main ways to transfer a file:

- **The clipboard**
- **The drag-and-drop feature**

Tracking clipboard content is an easy task since WinAPI provides the [clipboard format listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#creating-a-clipboard-format-listener), but my attempts to find something similar for the drag-and-drop operations are unsuccessful.

Is there any DragDrop buffer that could be read via WinAPI functionality? Or do I have to try a different approach for that?

I was thinking about listening `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message and getting the currently active window `HWND`. Thus, maybe (I haven't tested it yet) I will be able to disable the DragDrop feature using functions like [DragAcceptFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragacceptfiles) or [RevokeDragDrop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-revokedragdrop).

I would be glad to receive some recommendations and hints for further research. Not only about drag-and-drop, but also what can I do for the blocking 3rd party programs/utilities (*file managers and others, even cmd copy command*) that have a possibility to transfer a file?

Also, I must emphasize that in the future I plan to block copying by file format.

Comment: You need to read about [File System Filter Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/about-file-system-filter-drivers)

Comment: @RichardCritten I wrote about it below. My main goal now is to deal with these two mechanisms. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look! I must emphasize that in the future I plan to block copying by file type.

Comment: You started at the wrong end. The only way to override the user is to inject everywhere or be in the kernel with a driver.